# Need help looping macro

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I don't believe this is very difficult but I can't figure it out...

In column B, I have either "Original" or "Add" listed.  Starting from B79 and moving upwards, the first time "Original" is displayed I want to draw a border from B#:N# on the bottom.

I don't know how to run proper loops within VBA so below is what I have so far which is missing quite a bit.

```
Sub Test()    
Range("B79").Select
If Range("B79") = "Original" Then
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlDot
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

Else: ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
End If

End Sub
```

Here is my current attempt.  I am just trying to get it to highlight the cells.

```
Sub Test()

Let x = 79
Do While x > 7
If ("B" & x) = "Original" > 0 Then
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Else: x = x - 1
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Researching about "VBA loops" should tell you everything you ever dreamed to know about `For...Next`, `Do...Loop`, and every one of the 6 or 7 different (yet very similar) loop constructs in VBA. What have you tried, and how is it failing/not working? Can concatenate a number into a string to make a `Range` address? If so, then you can do `For i = 79 To 1 Step -1....Next`, and use the value of `i` to track the "current row".

Comment: I wouldn't be posting on this site if I haven't already tried researching this on my own...  I also didn't want to post my fruitless attempts which would cause extra confusion.   I've been able to cause a loop but not end it.

Comment: On the contrary, posting your fruitless attempts *shows us that you've tried something and how and why it's failing*, as opposed to looking like you're just asking for others to do the work for you - the more effort you've put in, the less your question looks like "gimmeh teh codez" and the more well-received it gets =)

Comment: That said you'll want to [avoid coding against Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513), for more robust and much simpler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for next loop and don't select, this should do what you need. Make sure you read this code and understand how it relates back to your original code.

```
Sub Test()
Dim X As Long
For X = 79 To 1 Step -1 'Step -1 makes it go backwards
    If Range("B" & X).Text = "Original" Then 'Notice I am not actually selecting anything in this code, I don't need to in order to manipulate it
        With Range("B" & X).End(xlToRight)
            For Each Border In .Borders 'Loop the borders so you don't have to name each one
                Border.LineStyle = xlNone
            Next
            With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlDot
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```